# How does the SpaceX Falcon 9 first-stage straighten for landing?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, landing, first-stage, droneship

I just saw this video of supposed "[SpaceX Rocket Camera Landing Footage Fakery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLE-ocDoXrs)" with over a million views.

The narrator repeatedly says it's complete garbage because he doesn't understand and would like to know:

> Now, you got a rocket at the bottom, how does this pencil, basically a flying pencil, regain itself and land straight down like this? ...
>
> [How does it] go from that position, I understand the rocket [at the bottom] but what is the mechanism to straighten it out after being basically parallel, and coming straight down? Someone wanna explain that?

Comment: Additional factor: the center of gravity is not in the middle, it's right at the bottom where the engine is. That gives a certain amount of drag stabilisation like a shuttlecock.

Comment: That video is *hillariously* bad.

Comment: That video is a classical case of *I don't understand how they do it, so it can't be done*. Instead of asking (here) he/she chose to make a video.

Comment: All you need to know about that video is in the comments. Commenter: "How did you come to believe that the earth is flat?" Video maker: "Watch my other videos. I explain it."

Comment: As someone who played Kerbal Space Program, I can say that the videomaker knows nothing about space or spaceships.

Comment: so that guy has no problem with the fact that that "pencil" can be pushed to space vertically (try to do that with a pencil), but can't understand how it comes back?

Comment: For what it's worth, the official webcast footage is [here](https://youtu.be/zBYC4f79iXc?t=27m44s).

Comment: @ardaozkal: To be fair, in this particular case the fact that it works in KSP doesn't say much, since KSP rockets have [magic](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/77936-ksp-vs-irl-reaction-wheels/) super-powered [reaction wheels](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Reaction_wheel#Real-World_Comparisons_and_Physics_Implications) that you can do [crazy](https://youtu.be/Dv1LuK7_I74), [crazy](https://youtu.be/hwm0rSCm8o8), [crazy](https://youtu.be/kgWPuhGSVKY), [crazy](https://youtu.be/kRW1ULhHPfU) stuff with.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yeah. KSP ones are indeed crazy, but you can also use cold gas thrusters to stabilize the ship even more.

Comment: I find it quite a mental leap to go from "I don't see how XYZ" to "XYZ is garbage".

Comment: @IlmariKaronen They aren't completely magic, you could get that sort of behavior with a very light structure and heavy reaction wheels. I made a toy RC ball with three reaction wheels that could spin up to their structural limits inside and it worked more-or-less like in KSP. It probably could launch itself off Deimos :)

Comment: @JanDoggen: This fallacy has a name: "Argument from personal incredulity".  I mention it because it is my favorite fallacy name.  http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Argument_from_incredulity

Comment: [0:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLE-ocDoXrs&t=0m30s) - "no audio" - LMFAO!

Comment: PZ Myers once wrote [There are no marching morons](http://scienceblogs.com/pharyngula/2007/05/08/there-are-no-marching-morons/). The creator of the cited video makes me think that Myers might be wrong.

Comment: Problem: this question is now generating excess views for that video... :)

Comment: Solution: Leave and live comments linking back here!

Answer (score 92):

Ironically, the answer is in his own (or rather SpaceX's) video.

[image]
 <sup>Still from 0:49 of the video showing cold gas thruster firing</sup>

The first stage of the Falcon 9 uses a set of nitrogen [cold gas thrusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_gas_thruster) to perform its flip after separation, and you can see them repeatedly firing in the video. As the compressed gas leaves the thruster its pressure drops very quickly, it condenses, and shows up as white puffs as the thrusters fire.

The thrusters are mounted on the interstage at the top of the first stage to provide the highest torque to orient the stage.

[image]
<sup>Thruster group highlighted with red circle</sup>

[Newton's Third Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_third_law) is one of those physical laws that is so blatantly obvious that everyone knows its result, but many people can't name it. If you've ever used a CO<sub>2</sub> fire extinguisher, you're familiar with the kick as the contents are released, this force can even [propel a tricycle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3k_TagfAJFY) or office chair. It is exactly that force from releasing compressed gas that allows the thrusters to operate and flip the stage.

[image]

<sup>OSHA violation</sup>

The first stage has an apogee of around 100km (depending on flight profile). At that altitude there is essentially no atmosphere (0.00003% of ground level ambient pressure), so aerodynamic control surfaces are completely useless for quickly flipping the stage.  However, after the entry burn (about 0:53 in the video) the stage rapidly encounters enough atmosphere to start using the [grid fins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_fin) for control.

[image]

<sup>Grid fins highlighted with red circles</sup>

The grid fins operate like any other aerodynamic control surface; they push air one direction, and good ol' Newton provides a force the other direction. For a practical demonstration get hold of a children's swing tennis set.

[image]

<sup>Future rocket scientists</sup>

Often the rackets are a good 20-30mm thick, so if you angle one as you swing you feel a force as the racket moves through the air.

Finally, as the stage performs the landing burn (about 1:00 in the video) we add in the main engines. The stage now becomes essentially an inverted pendulum supported by the firing engine/s. The inverted pendulum is a control problem that humanity has [Very](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyN-CRNrb3E). [Much](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15DIidigArA). [Solved](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=inverted%20pendulum&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=).

(see also [How is a rocket stabilized during the initial, slow speed, portion of launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12093/))

[image]
 <sup>Stooping Falcon</sup>

During the landing burn all three systems are in use, the engine/s are gimbaling, grid fins rotating, and thrusters firing (not visible in this video, but very obvious in the [CRS-6 landing video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhMSzC1crr0)).

Comment: Thanks, you can see the thrusters periodically going off during the whole descent. That video was sped up a bit, they're more evident in this [normal-speed clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z80PPH7DADA), and especially this [slowed-down one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-yWTH7SJDA).

Comment: Here's a [GIF of the thrusters](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x0XVy.gif) I think the torque is fairly small and is used to adjust the attitude before it hit's the atmosphere. Once that happens, I'd be surprised if those thrusters could have any influence at all compared to the aerodynamics of a cross-sectional area of almost 150 $m^2$ moving at mach speed through the atmosphere!

Comment: Thanks for the "Future rocket scientists" caption on one of the pictures. The best way to counter internet silliness is through humour!

Comment: "thrusters firing (not visible in this video...)" What do you call that big orange thing under the pointy thing?

Comment: @Aron I call it a main engine. It is an interesting point of nomenclature where we draw the line between thruster and engine. Usually thrusters are pressure-fed and control rotational or lateral velocity, whereas main engines are pump-fed and provide impulse in only one direction. There are many exceptions, so it's not really worth sticking to any one definition exclusively.

Comment: This is an outstanding answer -  well written and illustrated.

Comment: Sadly if the original YouTube poster sees this answer it will only confirm for him that it *is* fake - because "thrusters don't work in a vacuum because there's nothing to push against". Various flat-earth affiliates try to demonstrate this through woefully misconceived demonstrations, e.g. the balloon car with built-in reverser buckets here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuEXH8YV2R8

Comment: @TomGoodfellow [I give up.](https://youtu.be/752tGFuihzM)

Comment: More like "racket scientists"

Comment: "The first stage has an apogee of around 100km (depending on flight profile)." These days the first stage gets above 120 km. It reached 123 km on the May 26, 2021 launch.

Answer (score 30):

It's actually a combination of several systems:

- Nitrogen gas thrusters for attitude control in vacuum (one can see them firing in the video)
- 4 grid fins (two of them visible in the video) for attitude control during the atmospheric descent
- Gimbaled engines for attitude control during powered flight

Reference: [Falcon 9 User's Guide](http://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/falcon_9_users_guide_rev_2.0.pdf)

Comment: While the [YouTube Video of SpaceX Thaicom-8](https://youtu.be/zBYC4f79iXc?t=1664) does indeed call the "white puffs" cold nitrogen (a few seconds after 27:44), I'm not sure why they would be visible here in space. Are they becoming liquid nitrogen droplets? (@ForgeMonkey calls them $CO_2$ making "dry ice" crystals).  Here is [a GIF of it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x0XVy.gif). Do the grid fins do much at "final approach" to the drone ship? I thought they were only effective at fairly high velocity.

Comment: Yes. In the cold of space, the nitrogen quickly condenses again, I.e.

Comment: Regarding the grid fins, you can see them moving  few seconds before the touchdown (even during the final burn). Most clearly seen at around 1:10 in the slow-mo video https://youtu.be/b-yWTH7SJDA

Comment: ...plus the temperature drop associated with the expansion itself. Thanks - good to know!

Comment: I think that's like the Tyrannosaurus Rex's front arms moving - they're hooked up and getting signals, but it doesn't mean they are actually doing anything significant. Without high velocity, I don't think those tiny little paddles - that are mostly holes anyway - can generate enough torque to make a difference. I have a feeling that near the end, any significant attitude change comes from the thrust vectoring.

Comment: According to https://m.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/421js4/analysis_of_a_hoverslam_spacex_falcon_9_stage_1/ it decelerates at ~0.7 g. Given that, it would still be ~100 km/h at three seconds before touchdown. So the fins might still contribute to the overall torque until a few seconds before touchdown.

Comment: Instead of speculating, let's find out!! - I've [asked the question here](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/15507/12102).